# How to select a string and use it to find the difference between the times in Powershell

Tags: powershell, time, replace, split, difference

I have a text file that has a bunch of lines that logs my DNS. It records the time and the site that my devices request DNS.

I have the file located on c:\data

`$path = 'c:\data\dns.log'`

I tried to query the log by simple match for a word "xfinity"

`$Query = get-content -Path $path | Select-String -SimpleMatch "xfinity"`

Then I query the first time it requested and the last time it requested

`$Query | select -First 1`

`$Query | select -Last 1`

`$1st = $Query | select -First 1`

Then I tried to "isolate" just the time

`$1st -Split ("dnsmasq")`

and I got stuck below because I don't know how to select just the time. Did a lot of googling but most of the stuff just went over my head

Jan  7 15:31:14

[250]: query[A] [www.xfinity.com](http://www.xfinity.com) from 172.17.0.1

How do I just get the "time" of the first line and "time" of the last line and find the elapse time between them?

Here is an example of the dns.log would look like after Select-string to simple match "xfinity"

```
Jan  7 15:31:14 dnsmasq[250]: query[A] www.xfinity.com from 172.17.0.1
Jan  7 15:31:14 dnsmasq[250]: forwarded www.xfinity.com to 8.8.8.8
Jan  7 15:31:14 dnsmasq[250]: query[HTTPS] www.xfinity.com from 172.17.0.1
Jan  7 15:31:18 dnsmasq[250]: query[HTTPS] dss-dl-prod.aws-origin.xfinity.com from 172.17.0.1
Jan  7 15:31:18 dnsmasq[250]: forwarded dss-dl-prod.aws-origin.xfinity.com to 8.8.8.8
Jan  7 15:31:18 dnsmasq[250]: reply dss-dl-prod.aws-origin.xfinity.com is <CNAME>
Jan  7 15:33:18 dnsmasq[250]: reply dss-dl-prod.aws-origin.xfinity.com is <CNAME>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Generally, note that **[`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) does *not* directly return the *text* of matching lines**, it returns [`Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo) *objects* whose `.Line` property contains the line text, alongside *metadata*.

  - In *PowerShell (Core) 7+*, you can use the `-Raw` switch to *directly* request the text.
  - In *Windows PowerShell*, you must access the `.Line` property value explicitly, either via `(...).Line` or by piping to `Select-Object -ExpandProperty Line`
- Once you extract the actual *line text*, you'll be dealing with *strings*, so you'll need to *parse* those strings into the *fields* they contain.

  - The fields *before* `:` can unambiguously be extracted by using *whitespace* as the separator, which the unary form of the [`-split` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split) provides.
- You can interpret *strings* such as `15:31:14` as *time spans*, simply by casting them to the [`[timespan]`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.TimeSpan) .NET type.

To put it all together:

```bash
# Get the lines of interest.
# Note: In PowerShell Core 7+, you could simplify to:
#  $matchingLines = Get-Content $path | Select-String -Raw xfinity
$matchingLines = (Get-Content $path | Select-String xfinity).Line

# From the lines of interest, extract the first and last line.
$firstMatchingLine, $lastMatchingLine = $matchingLines[0], $matchingLines[-1]

# Calculate the elapsed time between
# the last and the first matching line.
[timespan] (-split $lastMatchingLine)[2] - (-split $firstMatchingLine)[2]
```

Comment: This worked flawlessly. I still don't understand the "split" part but will do more reading and practicing. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm glad to hear it, @Alessandro; my pleasure. The unary form of `-split` returns the array of whitespace-separated tokens, and `[2]` extracts the 3rd element from it.